# <?php _e( 'Sender Name', 'domain' ); ?>

Tags: php, wordpress

Its probably a rookie question but I try to adjust something in a script made by a developer that is no longer with me. Its relatively straightforward what I want to do but maybe not easy to implement.

Basically I have a WordPress plugin that had a form with labels on front of the text field. For Example "Sender Name" but if this is resized to mobile view it breaks the like and the 2 words are under each other.

The label is in a PHP string

```
<?php _e( 'Sender Name', 'textdomain' ); ?>
```

basically what I try to do is to format the "Some Text" to have less space when it is under each other.

[image: Label]

the space between vertical "Sender" and "Name" is fig and I try to somehow reduce this. Does anyone have a pointer for me to make this happen? I would appreciate the help.

Best wishes,

Thom

Comment: It is impossible to help without seeing the HTML and CSS - they are what are responsible for the display, so it depends entirely on that. Please update your question with a summary of what you have already tried yourself and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the lack of info.

Here is the whole Section: 

 <div class="nsc-start-order-send-mail">
  <span><?php _e( 'EMAIL', 'nsc'); ?> </span>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td><?php _e( 'Full Name', 'nsc'); ?> </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="nsc_start_order_full_name" id="nsc_start_order_full_name"></td>
    <td><div class="error-nsc-start-order-name"></div></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
 </div>

Answer (score 0):

As from the screenshot i think you have to try line-height

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-height/

Try to find the stylesheet loaded by inspecting the DOM and alter the line-height of the element, you may have to wrap the code in another element to achive cleaner code stracture like that

```
    <?php 
      echo '<span>'.__( 'Sender Name', 'textdomain' );.'</span>
    ?>
```

Comment: `line-height` is inappropriate for situations like this and it is overused as a hack for aligning text. What if the label wraps on a smaller screen? A larger line-height would mess up the display entirely.